# Bootstrap remove space on left of button

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, containers, bootstrap-modal

For some reason, my first button has a space before it and I can't get rid of it.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
        <button @onclick="ShowModal" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="oi oi-plus"></i>New Member</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3" style="margin:auto">
        <button @onclick="@RefreshData" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="oi oi-loop-circular"></i> Refresh Data</button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-4 offset-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Members" @bind="@searchTerm" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button @onclick="@SearchMember" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="oi oi-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This how it looks

[image]
This forces the search to go on the next row. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with margins; just make sure you get rid of the left margin. If you're ever in doubt about what a space is, take a peek at the element in dev tools and it'll normally help you out.

```css
div.container {
  margin-left: 0px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
        <button @onclick="ShowModal" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="oi oi-plus"></i>New Member</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3" style="margin:auto">
        <button @onclick="@RefreshData" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="oi oi-loop-circular"></i> Refresh Data</button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-4 offset-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Members" @bind="@searchTerm" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button @onclick="@SearchMember" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="oi oi-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am a noob at css. Will i put the margin removing code in my site.css or bootstrap.min.css? And what about the link?

Comment: No worries!

You'll want it in your site.css so you can access it easier later. You shouldn't really tamper with the bootstrap.min.css file unless you want to change something on your entire site. For example, if you wanted all the buttons to be orange, that's when you would change the "btn" class in the bootstrap file.

Ignore the link at the top, that just imports bootstrap into my code snippet there. Not relevant to you :P